# How to import a specific cell values from excel into a tkinter label box by selecting a factor from dropdown?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, dropdown, openpyxl

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
win=Tk()
BLOCK_NAME=StringVar()
VILLAGE_NA=StringVar()

wb = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Test data.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
xlsx_range = ws['B2':'B10']

elements = []
for cell in xlsx_range:
    for x in cell:
        y = x.value
        elements.append(y)
        print(y)

def lookupdata(event):
     print(combodata.get())

def lookupvillage():
    if combodata.get()==(Say B2):
        BLOCK_NAME.set([sheet["C2"].value])
    elif combodata.get()==(Say B3):
        BLOCK_NAME.set([sheet["C3"].value])
    elif combodata.get()==(Say B4):
        BLOCK_NAME.set([sheet["C4"].value])
              
Label(win, text="Select data").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=clicked, width=30)
combodata['values']=elements
combodata.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=50, pady=50)
combodata.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lookupdata)
    
lbl3=Label(win, text="Block", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("times new roman",15,"bold")).grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent3=Entry(win, textvariable=BLOCK_NAME, width=20, state='readonly')
ent3.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

btn = Button(win, text = 'Calculate Value', command=lookupvillage, bd = '5', width=15, height=2)
btn.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)

win.mainloop()
```

I have prepared this code which helps in creating a dropdown from excel values in Tkinter. But I want that when a particular value is selected from the dropdown, then data in the same row from excel should be chosen and set in the label boxes in Tkinter. Like if the value in the dropdown selected is in the B2 cell, I want the C2 value in the label automatically. I have more than 1000 values in the dropdown so it would be difficult with if-elif statements, guide me in this also (For loop might be helpful). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you wanted me to look here. I don't work with `openpyxl`, so I am not sure here.

Comment: One way to eliminate the if statements to to find a way to calculate the cell identifier from the value returned by `combodata.get()`. Are these values unique for each row? If so, you just find which row contains that value. Or better yet, store the row along with the value that is displayed in the UI.

Comment: It will help a lot if you will provide some example rows from the excel file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I have a query that I have mentioned in an answer below or u can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346170/how-to-import-specific-cell-values-from-excel-by-giving-input-from-tkinter-dropd
Can u shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: since you didn't provide any sample data, I made my own, using this function:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

def create_sample_workbook():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.create_sheet("Sheet1")
    columns = {
        "B": ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta",    "echo",  "foxtrot", "golf",   "hotel", "india", "juliet"],
        "C": ["kilo",  "lima",  "mike",    "november", "oscar", "papa",    "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango"]
    }
    for column_letter, col in columns.items():
        for i, value in enumerate(col,1):
            ws[f"{column_letter}{i}"] = value
    wb.save("Test data.xlsx")

create_sample_workbook()
```

Your results may look different from mine since our data is different.

I also had to change your `combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=clicked, width=30)` to `combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, width=30)` In order to fix a NameError in your code. I don't think this is directly related to your problem.

---

> For loop might be helpful.

That's one valid approach, yes. within `lookupvillage`, iterate over the rows you're interested in, and see if the combobox matches the row's B column.

```
def lookupvillage():
    value = combodata.get()
    for i in range(2, 11):
        if value == ws.cell(i, 2).value:
            BLOCK_NAME.set(ws.cell(i, 3).value)
            return
    #couldn't find a matching value. Maybe the blank item is still selected?
    BLOCK_NAME.set("unknown")
```

Result:

[image]

---

You can also save a little lookup time by pre-preparing a dictionary that maps B column values to their corresponding C and D values. Put this just below `ws = wb['Sheet1']`:

```
data = {} #todo: pick a more descriptive name that explains what kind of data is in B and C and D
for i in range(2,11):
    data[ws.cell(i,2).value] = {"C": ws.cell(i,3).value, "D": ws.cell(i,4).value}
```

Now you can quickly find C and D values for any B value, no loop required:

```
def lookupvillage():
    value = combodata.get()
    if value in data:
        BLOCK_NAME.set(data[value]["C"])
    else:
        BLOCK_NAME.set("unknown")
```

Comment: Hey Kevin thnxx a lot for the code, can u please have a look at my answer below, I am facing same difficulty but this time columns also vary. I have prepared a code but not getting the desired result.