# How to import specific cell values from excel by giving input from tkinter dropdown?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, drop-down-menu, openpyxl

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

win=Tk()

BLOCK_NAME=StringVar()
VILLAGE_NA=StringVar()
head=StringVar()

# Load the xlsx file, then store the value of each column in the "elements" list
wb = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Master_Db.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
xlsx_range = ws['B2':'B21']
head_range = ws['P1':'AI1']
vill = []
yr=[]
for cell in xlsx_range:
    for x in cell:
        y = x.value
        vill.append(y)

for cell in head_range:
    for x1 in cell:
        y1=x1.value
        yr.append(y1)

def lookupdata(event):
    print(combodata.get())

def lookuphead():
    value1=comboy.get()
    for j in range(16, 20):
        for i in range(2, 11):
            if value1 == ws.cell(1, j).value:
                head.set(ws.cell(i, j).value)
                return
def lookupvillage():
    value = combodata.get()
    for i in range(2, 11):
        if value == ws.cell(i, 2).value:
            BLOCK_NAME.set(ws.cell(i, 3).value)
            TEHSIL_NAM.set(ws.cell(i, 4).value)
            DISTRICT_N.set(ws.cell(i,5).value)
            return
    #couldn't find a matching value. Maybe the blank item is still selected?
    BLOCK_NAME.set("unknown")


Label(win, text="Select the Year", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("times new roman",15,"bold")).grid(row=11, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='w')
comboy=ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=optsy, width=20, state='readonly')
comboy['values']=yr
comboy.grid(row=11, column=1,padx=10, pady=5)
comboy.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")


Label(win, text="Select data").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
combodata=ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable=clicked, width=30)
combodata['values']=elements
combodata.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=50, pady=50)
combodata.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lookupdata)

lbl3=Label(win, text="Block", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("times new roman",15,"bold")).grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='w')
ent3=Entry(win, textvariable=BLOCK_NAME, width=20, state='readonly')
ent3.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

lbl6=Label(win, text="Head", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("times new roman",15,"bold")).grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky='w')
ent6=Entry(win, textvariable=head, width=15, state='readonly')
ent6.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')


btn = Button(win, text = 'Calculate Value',command=lambda:[lookupvillage(), lookuphead()] , bd = '5', width=15, height=2)
btn.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)
win.mainloop()
```

I have this code now I want to add another factor in it that is as I select a particular year from dropdown and village from another, I want the cross-sectional value. e.g village from dropdown=ABAD GARH & Year chosen= 2021, value in Head label should be =8.41. Similarly if I select 2022 it should be 8.02 and so on for all.

Comment: Break this down into small steps: first you need to find the row that contains "abad garh" then you need to get the cell in the column for the chosen year.

Comment: If you only do this look up a few times, searching the Excel file is fine. If you need to search a lot of times, then you should parse the file into a data structure that allows faster look ups.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have a data of 1000 rows with 35 columns but want to work in excel only as my code is almost ready.......just this step is remaining.

Comment: My first comment explains how you can approach this.